# How do i get string between two string

Tags: php, string

i have one string and i need to get text between text

Scenario

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMPID > 0
```

from above string i need to get

```
array([0]=>'*',[1]=>'EMP')

function BetweenStr($InputString, $StartStr, $EndStr=0, $StartLoc=0) 
{
    if (($StartLoc = strpos($InputString, $StartStr, $StartLoc)) === false) { return; }
    $StartLoc += strlen($StartStr);
    if (!$EndStr) { $EndStr = $StartStr; }
    if (!$EndLoc = strpos($InputString, $EndStr, $StartLoc)) { return; }
    return substr($InputString, $StartLoc, ($EndLoc-$StartLoc));
}
```

above function works if i give $InputString, $StartStr and $EndStr but if i did not pass $EndStr it's not work

```
$hd_qa['SELECT'] = $this->BetweenStr($myQuery,'SELECT','FROM');
**Result => *
$hd_qa['FROM'] = $this->BetweenStr($myQuery,'FROM','WHERE');
**Result => EMP
$hd_qa['WHERE'] = $this->BetweenStr($myQuery,'WHERE','');
** NOT WORKING
```

Comment: Try to read in into the powerful, magical world of regular expressions.

Comment: Is the string going to be a fixed format? Because `explode` will do this more easily than regular expressions.

Comment: no its a dynamic string

Comment: @NoorKhan - ... how dynamic? Explode the string on spaces, and you can separate out the individual elements with ease, and it doesn't matter if the table name changes (well, unless your table names have spaces, at least)

Comment: system will generate query depend on selected options it up to them what they selected and show in parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$matches = array();
$sql = 'SELECT blah blah blah FROM EMP WHERE EMPID > 0';
preg_match('/SELECT(.+?)FROM(.+?)WHERE(.+)/is', $sql, $matches);
print_r($matches);

echo $matches[1];  // These are what you're looking for
echo $matches[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it your way, doing like that should do the trick :

```
function BetweenStr($InputString, $StartStr, $EndStr=0, $StartLoc=0) 
{
    if (($StartLoc = strpos($InputString, $StartStr, $StartLoc)) === false) { return; }
    $StartLoc += strlen($StartStr);
    if (!$EndStr) { $EndLoc = strlen($InputString); }
    if (!$EndLoc = strpos($InputString, $EndStr, $StartLoc)) { return; }
    return substr($InputString, $StartLoc, ($EndLoc-$StartLoc));
}
```